# XSL-FO - Why Overflow in fo:block in fo:list-block - contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in the inline-progression direction by 997

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I generate a List with XSL-Fo. The list in the PDF looks good. :-)

But I get the following **Warning**:

**[WARN] FOUserAgent - The contents of fo:block line 1 exceed the available area in the inline-progression direction by 997 millipoints. (See position 522:27)**

This is the Code I am using:

```
<fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="3mm" end-indent="3mm" start-indent="3mm">
 <fo:list-item>
  <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
  <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
  </fo:list-item-label>
  <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
    <fo:block>List Text 1</fo:block>
  </fo:list-item-body>
 </fo:list-item>
</fo:list-block>
```

**For instance, if I remove the "•", the warning disappears.**

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks a lot in advance.

I want to have no warning.

Comment: 997 millipoints = 1/3 mm.
I suppose that bullet is minimal more than that.
You could alter the attributes of fo:list-block to see if that solves the problem.
Otherwise you have to change something in the ancestor properties of  fo:list-block so it has more space

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: set `provisional-label-separation` to something smaller than 6pt and/or increase `provisional-distance-between-starts`.

---

See the second graphic in Section 6.8, "Formatting Objects for Lists" of XSL 1.1 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e12374).

When you specify both `<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">` and `<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">`, the width of the list item label is determined by the `provisional-label-separation` and `provisional-distance-between-starts` values.

You specified `provisional-distance-between-starts="3mm"`, but you didn't specify `provisional-label-separation`, so it has its initial value of 6pt (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#provisional-label-separation).  The specified width of the list item label is, therefore, 3mm - 6pt, or not very much at all.

This graphic shows your sample formatted in the Antenna House Formatter GUI.  The ruler unit is 'pt'.  With the initial 6pt `provisional-label-separation` length, you can see both that the list item label doesn't have much space and that the bullet overflows the allocated space.

[image: List item shown in Antenna House Formatter GUI. Ruler shows 6pt separation between label and body.]

You can change one or both of `provisional-label-separation` and `provisional-distance-between-starts` to give the list item label more width and avoid the overflow. Or decrease the size of the bullet, which you probably don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the values solved it :-).

This Documentations was very useful:  https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/contrib/FOP/list.pdf

This is the solution:

```
`<fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="3mm" provisional-label- 
separation="1.5mm" start-indent="1.5mm">
<fo:list-item>
<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
<fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
<fo:block>List Text 1</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
</fo:list-block>`
```